# do request.setAttribute in jsp page and request.getAttribute in java code

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Is this possible that i do request.setAttribute in jsp code and retrive the value using request.getAttribute in java struts code.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I debugged and i got null value.

Comment: But my question is that right to do.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I am pasting an answer from already asked question [Using request.setAttribute in a JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229937/using-request-setattribute-in-a-jsp-page)

No. Unfortunately the Request object is only available until the page finishes loading - once it's complete, you'll lose all values in it unless they've been stored somewhere.

If you want to persist attributes through requests you need to either:

1.Have a hidden input in your form, such as " />. This will then be available in the servlet as a request parameter.

2.Put it in the session (see request.getSession() - in a JSP this is available as simply session)

I recommend using the Session as it's easier to manage.

Comment: How longer will this session persists.

Comment: It depends upon your configuration.