# Why does ServletRequest have setAttribute, instead of ServletResponse?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I don't understand why ServletRequest has a setAttribute method.
Eg:
 if i have a jsp page containing 1 textbox and a submit button...

My objective is when i submit **my name should be displayed in that textbox**.
Question here: whatever is displayed in that textbox is **response** from servlet right?

But in my assignment in servlet part:
It was written **request.setAttribute("name","abc");**

at jsp side:
It was written: `<input type="text" value = < %request.getAttribute("name")% > >`

I know in javadocs they have setattribute inside request but why not under response?

Comment: check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/229957/1460591

Comment: yes checked but its not what i asked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Request : From Client to Server**

**Response: From Server to Client**

When your client sends your servlet request, you add object in request and later retrieves it in jsp.The request is passed from servlet to jsp.Your jsp retrieves the object,generates a HTML and sends it as response back to your browser.The same request sent by your client is passed from one servlet or jsp to another jsp or servlet and then these are compiled to generate HTML format and sent to browser as response from server.Setting object in response doesnot make sense because browser just displays HTML.

Answer (score 6):

when they say request.setAttribute(Object, Object) it is simply to imply that the scope of the attribute is for that request only and the attribute will not exist in subsequent requests. Displaying data on a JSP like your name in the textbox is task that is still in the scope of the request. You are attaching the data to the request object.

Comment: this is much clearer and concise than the rest of the answers

Answer (score 6):

Because I think setting the attribute of a response makes no sense. You can go to a hotel and order for lunch. This is request, and what you want for lunch, that is a request's Attribute. But the quality of the food i.e. response entirely depends on the hotel (the server). Similarly
when a Web server responds to a HTTP request to the browser, the response typically consists of a status line, some response headers, and the document (optional, like any JSON data or something similar). So if you have response.setAttribute i.e means you can change the name of the browser from Mozilla to Chrome, but that's insane.