# request.getAttribute() is not working in servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i am trying to set the value using request attribute in jsp , i am trying to get the value in servlets using request.getAttribute(), but request.getAttribute() is giving null value

this is my code in jsp:

```
<form action="action.do" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return submit_form()">

<input type="hidden" name="id" parameter="id" value="<%=id%>" >
request.setAttribute("validTillDate",validtilldate);
```

in Servlets:

```
String vaidTillDate=(String)request.getAttribute(validTillDate);
System.out.println("date is:"+validTillDate)  // output is : date is : null
```

Comment: Should use <% request.setAttribute("validTillDate",validtilldate); %>...right?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think that you can't set an attribute in a jsp.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229937/using-request-setattribute-in-a-jsp-page

Comment: Why don't you just add another hidden input field like you already did for the ID? What were you thinking/expecting? I'd suggest to learn basic HTTP as well, lifecycle of HTTP request/response and so on. This will improve your understanding of "under the covers" working of JSP/Servlet.

Comment: @TroyAndAbed i got some trouble with that link. In place of hidden what type i should use

Comment: @BalusC I have two attributes to send from jsp to servlets , so it is not possible

Comment: If you understood basic HTTP, you'd have realized that it makes no utter sense what you're trying. So, start learning HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding another hidden for **'validtilldate'**

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" parameter="id" value="<%=id%>" >
<input type="hidden" name="validtilldate" parameter="validtilldate" value="<%=validtilldate%>" >
```

Comment: Thank you for posting answer