# How to Display Values in Jsp Page from Action Class

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have written some code for displaying values in input box  using **jsp** ,Values coming from **Action** class.

```
request.setAttribute("Admissionno",studentdata.get(0));
request.setAttribute("Empname",studentdata.get(1));
```

Below is the Jsp Code:

```
<table id="biometric">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Admission No</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Attendence</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="30" name="admission" readonly="readonly"  
                       value="%=request.getAttribute("Admissionno")%>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="30" name="empName"
                readonly="readonly" value=""></input></td>
            <td><select name="status" size="1">
                    <option value="Present">Present</option>
                    <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
                    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
                    <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                    <option value="NA">NA</option>
            </select></td>

        </tr>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

In **Action** class values are coming,
But  Values are not displayed in **Jsp**.

when using scriptlet **Jsp** is not working.

please provide the any other solution.

Comment: do not use request.setAttribute() in jsp the value does not remain once the page finishes loading. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229937/using-request-setattribute-in-a-jsp-page

Comment: Here am passing some parameters,based on that values is getting from database.So same jsp  using two times. Once values sending  and getting ,if i use session previous values is displayed, not current request

Comment: in case you want to persist values in case of url redirects and page refreshes use session.setAttribute instead.

Comment: your scriptlet tag is incomplete <%=request.getAttribute("Admissionno")%>

Comment: Which version of Struts are you using?